# Python - Running a SQL in a loop based on column value

Tags: python, sql, loops

I am trying to build a SQL query that runs based on certain conditions (if a column is filled run Query 1 else Query 2 and so on) as shown below:

```
if len(col_a) > 0 and len(col_b) > 0: ## Both columns have value
    dwh_cursor.execute(f"""select * from table where col_a = '{col_a}' and col_b = '{col_b}'""")

elif len(col_a) > 0 and len(col_b) < 1: ## Only col_a has value
    dwh_cursor.execute(f"""select * from table where col_a = '{col_a}'""")

elif len(col_a) < 1 and len(col_b) > 0: ## Only col_b has value
    dwh_cursor.execute(f"""select * from table where col_b = '{col_b}'""")
```

I am trying to build something like the above but the number of fields as variable (fields like `col_a` and `col_b`) are 6 in number. Is there a way I can perform this in a loop based on the length of field, instead of having to manually have each condition explicitly mentioned as I have done above.

Comment: did you know Python string functions and string formatting ? ie `"and ".join(["col_a = '{col_a}'", "col_b = '{col_b}'"])`and `["{name} = {{{name}}}" for name in ["col_a", "col_b"]]`

Comment: first you should keep columns on list `col[0]`, `col[1]` or in dict `col["a"]`, `col["b"]` - and then you can use loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep values on list or in dictionary and then you can use `for`-loop to filter empty elements.

Later you can use string functions and `for`-loop to convert to `col = val` and `join()` to connect these elements using word `AND`, etc.

```
where = {
    'col_a': '',   # empty so it will skip it
    'col_b': 'A',
    'col_c': '1',
}

where_filtered = {key:val for key, val in where.items() if val}

print('where filtered:', where_filtered)

where_parts = [f'{key} = {val}' for key, val in where_filtered.items()]

print('where parts:', where_parts)

where_query = ' and '.join(where_parts)

print('where query:', where_query)

query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
if where_query:
    query += ' WHERE ' + where_query
    
print('query:', query)
```

Results:

```
where filtered: {'col_b': 'A', 'col_c': '1'}
where parts: ['col_b = A', 'col_c = 1']
where query: col_b = A and col_c = 1
query: SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_b = A and col_c = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the output. That helped.. Got one question on this. When I run the SQL `cursor.execute(query)` it fails. I believe it is because for `col_b` in the where clause it expect `col_b = 'A'`.. How could I alter this to pass it in the right format. Thanks..

Comment: figured it out. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `f"{key} = '{val}'"`

Comment: BTW: I used word `where` in code because in similar way you can use it also for `order by`, `group by`, etc.